GraphQL with Apollo server + PostgreSQL not returning correct response
I am new to graphQL and Apollo server and developing a small POC app to understand the concepts.
I am simply trying to connect to DB(Postgres) and fetching(Query) and updating(Mutate) the data.
I have written below code so far:
index.ts
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { BooksDataSource } from "./dataStores/booksDataStore.js";

const typeDefs = gql(
    readFileSync("./src/schemas/books.graphql", {
        encoding: "utf-8",
    })
);

interface ContextValue {
    dataSources: {
        booksDB: BooksDataSource;
    };
}

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        // @ts-ignore
        allBooks: () => async (_, __, { dataSources }) => {
            console.log(`Here`)
            return await dataSources.booksDB.getAllBooks();
        },
        bookById: async (_, { id }, { dataSources }) => {
            return await dataSources.booksDB.getBookById(id);
        }
    },
};

const server = new ApolloServer<ContextValue>({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
});

const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
    context: async ({ req }) => {
        return {
            dataSources: {
                booksDB: new BooksDataSource()
            }
        };
    },
    listen: { port: 4000 },
});

console.log(`  Server ready at: ${url}`);

books.graphql
type Book {
    id: String
    title: String
    author: String
}

type Query {
  allBooks: [Book]
    bookById(id: String!): Book
}

type Mutation {
  addBook(title: String!, author: String!): Book!
}

booksDataStore.ts
import {DataTypes, Sequelize} from "sequelize";

export class BooksDataSource {
    private static dbConnection: Sequelize | null = null;
    private static book: any = null;

    constructor() {
        if(!BooksDataSource.dbConnection) {
            void this.initializeDBConnection();
        }
    }

    async initializeDBConnection() {
        const connectionString = 'postgresConnectionString'
        const sequelize = new Sequelize(connectionString);

        // Define the Book model
        BooksDataSource.book = sequelize.define('Book', {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            title: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
            },
            author: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
            }
        }, {
            tableName: 'books'
        });

        try {
            await sequelize.authenticate();
            await sequelize.sync();
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
        }

        BooksDataSource.dbConnection = sequelize;
    }

    async getBookById(bookId) {
        console.log(`getBookById`)
        try {
            return await BooksDataSource.book.findByPk(bookId);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching book by ID:', error);
        }
    }

    async getAllBooks() {
        console.log(`getAllBooks`)
        try {
            return await BooksDataSource.book.findAll();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching book by ID:', error);
        }
    }
}

So when I start the server I get below:
> npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js


> graphql-server-example@1.0.0 compile
> tsc

  Server ready at: http://localhost:4000/
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Executing (default): SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'books'
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'books' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Connection has been established successfully.


But when I hit the request from Apollo Sandbox I get the below response and for debugging, I have put some consoles, but none of them is coming in my console.
My understanding is, that If I hit the request, it should ideally go to the resolver and then the console console.log(Here) should get printed as the entry point and later on inside the booksDataStore.ts other consoles should be printed.
I don't have any data in my database, but the connection is working fine and the books table gets created. Even if I don't have any data, it should not give me this error and the console should at least be printed but nothing is happening.
Appreciate any help!


My guess is, getAllBooks() fails with error and as a result resolver for allBooks return undefined which cause the error you see.
 Query: {
        // @ts-ignore
        allBooks: () => async (_, __, { dataSources }) => {
            console.log(`Here`)
            return await dataSources.booksDB.getAllBooks();
        },
    .... 

Take a closer look here:
    async getAllBooks() {
        console.log(`getAllBooks`)
        try {
            return await BooksDataSource.book.findAll();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching book by ID:', error);
        }
    }

If there is any error happened (for instance your app could not establish connection to the database or something else) during BooksDataSource.book.findAll(); call, getAllBooks()  will return undefined instead of an array.
I would suggest to remove try-catch to be able to see what the actual error is:
    async getAllBooks() {
        console.log(`getAllBooks`)
        return await BooksDataSource.book.findAll();
    }

